# Newcomer's Rhyming Riddle II - What Am I?

Tags: riddle, word

> Followed by the shade of the envious French;
>   Followed by fighters, in water or trench.
>   Before a stroke limit, unruly or weak;
>   Before a sour citrus, performing at peak.
>   Its path involves rails, deep under the ground;
>   Or even machines, playing extra deep sounds.
>   When allowed, it may rent you a flat or a house;
>   But when mixed, it's the port for a cable or mouse.
>   Before a book's name, helps the foreign and deaf;
>   Alone, it's a shorthand for a deli-bound chef.

**What am I?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is

> a **SUB**

Followed by the shade of the envious French;

> **sub**vert, *vert* being "green" in French (thanks @M Oehm)

Followed by fighters, in water or trench.

> **sub**marines

Before a stroke limit, unruly or weak;

> **sub**-par

Before a sour citrus, performing at peak.

> **sub**lime

Its path involves rails, deep under the ground;

> **sub**way

Or even machines, playing extra deep sounds.

> **sub**woofer

When allowed, it may rent you a flat or a house;

> **sub**let (or perhaps sublease)

But when mixed, it's the port for a cable or mouse.

> **sub** rearranges to USB

Before a book's name, helps the foreign and deaf;

> **sub**title

Alone, it's a shorthand for a deli-bound chef.

> **sub**

Comment: The colour of the envious French is _vert_ (green), although in French, envy may also be [associated with yellow](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolisme_des_couleurs).

Comment: @MOehm Thank you - I was stumbling around in the dark with Google Translate. :)

Comment: I think it is definitely *sublet*, because "allow" means "let".

Comment: Amusingly, USB is also an anagram of BUS, which is what the B in USB stands for!